# Can I deploy a service to a docker swarm via a docker-compose.yml file that references the image by its ID?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I create a docker-compose.yml file that references docker images by ID.  When I try to deploy the compose file to a swarm, I get the error "No such image: 2e69080faee3:latest" repeatedly.

The image *does* exist locally.  In my scenario, it was loaded from a tar file that was provided to me by an upstream process.

Here is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  registry:
    image: 2e69080faee3
```

And here is the output from `docker images` that includes this image on the local node:
[image: docker images output]

I'm not sure if I should expect this situation to work or not?  I am struggling to find documentation that says this should *NOT* work, but there's nothing that explicitly says that it *SHOULD* work, either.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#image), yes, in compose version `3.2`.

Comment: Agreed that the documentation claims it's supported... but it does not *appear* to be working in my scenario, which is confusing...